# Express + Sqlite3: How to have statements execute in a certain order?

Tags: javascript, express, sqlite, node-sqlite3

I am trying to create a table with an item inserted into it upon executing the following script using the `node` command. However, for some reason my code is inserting the item into the table before the table is even created. I tried swapping the indexes of my statements, but they were still executed in the same order. When I open up the database with `sqlite3` and manually put in the commands, everything works as expected. Is there any way to specify which statement goes first in my script?

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
const app = express();

app.use(cors());

let db = new sqlite3.Database("./database.db", err => {
    try {
        console.log("Successful connection to the database");
    } catch {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
});

statements = ["CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Products (product TEXT, price INTEGER);", "INSERT INTO Products (product, price) VALUES ('Apple', 5.99);"]
statements.forEach(statement => db.run(statement, err => {
    try {
        console.log(statement + ": successful!");
    } catch {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
}));

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Connection: http://localhost:3000/")
})
```

**Output:**

```
Connection: http://localhost:3000/
Successful connection to the database
INSERT INTO Products (product, price) VALUES ('Apple', 5.99);: successful!
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Products (product TEXT, price INTEGER);: successful!
```

Comment: Consider using  [Database.serialize](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/statements-control-flow/) if you want to guarantee the execution order of statements

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of the **db.run** in your foreach statement which is asynchronous.  Try this:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
// connect to database
let db = new sqlite3.Database("./database.db", err => {
  if (err) { // if fail connection don't create table
    console.error(err.message);
  } else {
    console.log("Successful connection to the database");

    // Create table first
    db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Products (product TEXT, price INTEGER);", err => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      } else {
        console.log("Table created successfully");

        // Insert data after table creation
        db.run("INSERT INTO Products (product, price) VALUES ('Apple', 5.99);", err => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
          } else {
            console.log("Data inserted successfully");
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Connection: http://localhost:3000/")
});
```